# Помогите с циклом и массивом данных с файла с ссылками

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

Есть такой код, в нем я считываю с файла ссылки htp://site1.aa,htp://site3.aa,htp://site2.aa
Помещаю в массив $pieces разделитель запятая. В цикле передаю каждую ссылку вот сюда $h = file_get_html($value);
После этого мне нужно найти по селекторам нужный элемент и вывести его например на страницу.

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.txt', true);
// echo $file;
$pieces = explode(",", $file);
print_r($pieces);

foreach ($pieces as $key => $value) {
$h = file_get_html($value);

$title = $h->find('p.b-product-cost__price') ;
echo $title ->plaintext;
}
```

Исправил немного код и хочу например в цикле вывести цены, в этом случае должно получиться три варианты, поскольку ссылок в текстовом файле 3.
В результате получаю таки ошибки

Warning: file_get_contents( https://kristan.org.ua/p341665825-shibernaya-zadvizhka-pvh.html): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in D:\WebServers2\OSPanel\domains\localhost\pars\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Warning: file_get_contents( https://kristan.org.ua/p341670478-shibernaya-zadvizhka-pvh.html): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in D:\WebServers2\OSPanel\domains\localhost\pars\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Warning: file_get_contents( ): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in D:\WebServers2\OSPanel\domains\localhost\pars\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in D:\WebServers2\OSPanel\domains\localhost\pars\a.php on line 56

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего Вы перепутали массив(`$pieces`) со элементом массива(`$value`)

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.txt', true);
// echo $file;
$pieces = explode(",", $file);
print_r($pieces);

foreach ($pieces as $key => $value) {
$h = file_get_html($value);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Но все равно не работает как мне нужно. Вот что у меня получилось в результате